# php override vendor package class method

Tags: php, composer-php

What is the proper way to change a package installed through composer in the vendor folder.

A: copy the package directory to the project source (so it is not changed by composer anymore) and use it from there.

B: Extend the class.

I would think that B is the proper way, but i see two problems with it. 
1. The extended class may not be compatible with an updated baseclass from the vendor directory. (after "composer update")
2. How do I manipulate a method way down in the class chain.

```
$classA = new ClassA();
$classB = $classA->getsomeOtherClassInstance();
$classB->methodToChange();
```

I.e. I would have to change class A and B to make sure that the extended version of B is called.

Comment: forking it in a private repository then edit it as you want , then use it as an individual package , this will prevent 're-overriding' the package to the original package in case of you want to update your vendors .

Comment: @HassanAhmed using as an individual package... do you mean that I would add it to composer and be my own vendor, or just have it sit in a directory outside the vendor folder.

Comment: There's also a third way: composition.

Answer (score 0):

1. The extended class may not be compatible with an updated baseclass from the vendor directory. (after "composer update")

The class should always be backwards compatible if you choose the correct version number in your composer.json file. Take a look at https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md (Keep in mind this only applies for code repositories that promise backwards compatibility, but most big names do.)

Also, if you want you can choose a concrete version like for example '3.7.7' which would prevent composer update from updating your code, will always use that version. But better to do the above.

2. How do I manipulate a method way down in the class chain.

If it is a private method then you were not meant to change it, better to look for its caller and override that method and class instead. Also, take a look at Decorator design pattern it allows you to change behavior of methods dynamically on the fly.

Comment: it's not a private method, it's public. Maybe I got some core concept wrong of class extention.